# Application Crash - EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) - iOS 4.3 - three20

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, three20, sigabrt

I have included three20 library in my project. I am making use of the TTThumbsViewController. Everything was working great until i upgraded to Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3. The grid of photos appears fine, but as soon as i click on one the thumbs, the app crashes. I am certain that this is not a memory issue. It works fine on the simulator though. Here is the crash report :

> Incident Identifier: 3C63956F-F718-468F-B113-116E457DEB4E
>   CrashReporter Key:   32180af33b999869f98369f8d85412b799a88fdb
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
>   Process:         MyApp [15071]
>   Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/13C32157-F4CA-44BC-BB8F-D9A9FE9EAE38/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Identifier:      MyApp
>   Version:         ??? (???)
>   Code Type:       ARM (Native)
>   Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-05-06 21:48:06.042 -0500
>   OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3 (8F190)
>   Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00011a1c __pthread_kill + 8
>   1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000333b4 pthread_kill + 52
>   2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0002bbf8 abort + 72
>   3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
>   4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000606c _objc_terminate + 104
>   5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e36 _*cxxabiv1::*_terminate(void (*)()) + 46
>   6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e8a std::terminate() + 10
>   7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f5a __cxa_throw + 78
>   8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
>   9   CoreFoundation                  0x0009e48a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
>   10  CoreFoundation                  0x0009e4c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
>   11  QuartzCore                      0x00001616 CALayerSetPosition(CALayer*, CA::Vec2 const&, bool) + 134
>   12  QuartzCore                      0x00001584 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 32
>   13  QuartzCore                      0x000014d0 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 384
>   14  UIKit                           0x0000544e -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 182
>   15  MyApp                           0x00078366 -[TTPhotoView layoutSubviews] (TTPhotoView.m:221)
>   16  UIKit                           0x000055f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate)
>   layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 20
>   17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000befc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
>   18  QuartzCore    0x00002bae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 114

Any ideas anyone ?

Thanks

Comment: "I am certain that this is not a memory issue. It works fine on the simulator though."  Its working fine on the simulator does *not* mean there are not memory issues—once you start stomping on memory, you enter Undefined Behavior land, and anything can happen, including both crashing and silently succeeding.

Comment: I agree..But i ran build and analyze, instruments with nszombieenabled and couldn't find any memory related problems..

Comment: What's the exception being thrown? It should be logged to the console, and knowing what exactly it is will help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes..It was a NaN that was being passed. Basically if you use the constructor(MockPhotoSource class) which by default assigns a null value to the caption variable, it throws this exception. So i used the other constructor and gave a blank value to the caption parameter

Answer (score 4):

The function `CALayerSetPosition` is throwing an exception of type `NSException`, and nobody is catching it, so your application is getting terminated.  Try adding this code around the call to `-[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:]` inside the function `-[TTPhotoView layoutSubviews]` (which should be on line 221 of TTPhotoView.m):

```
@try
{
    [myUIView setFrame:someFrame];
}
@catch(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"Caught exception: %@", exception);
}
```

That should give you more information about why the exception is being thrown; most likely, you're passing an invalid parameter or something.

Comment: this together with a breakpoint inside the catch was really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also just recently saw this exception and per what Adam said, I believe the problem is that a NaN is being passed in as a parameter and this is throwing the exception. If it's the same problem I was facing, I was able to comment the line out to just get around the problem (AFAICT the line is only dealing with the loading spinner progress indicator).  So if you're willing to live w/o that, you can get around it